# Can't connect to dBase files from web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, odbc, jet, dbase

I have a web app, written about 10 years ago (VB.NET/ASP).
It uses the following connection string to connect to dBase 5 files:

```
Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=[SOURCE_PATH];
```

This has been working great for years. 
Now we are moving this app to a 64 bit server, and this connection is now giving me

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I've read numerous suggestions in numerous threads, including changing the above connection string to

```
Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; or Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.
```

but that didn't do anything.

I also tried setting Enable 32-Bit Applications settings on the application pool on the web server to TRUE, but that resulted in

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction please??

Comment: Is your app 32-bit or 64-bit? There's almost certainly only a 32-bit version of your driver available so your app would need to be 32-bit to use it.

Comment: Also, if you switch from an ODBC connection string to an OLE DB connection string then you'd have to change all your ADO.NET objects from `Odbc` to `OleDb` too but there's still no 64-bit version of Jet anyway.

Comment: The app is 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your connection string from

```
Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=[SOURCE_PATH];
```

to

```
Driver={Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[SOURCE_PATH];Extended Properties=dBASE 5.0;}
```

You also have to change your code from ODBC objects (DataSet, etc), to OLEDB objects.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!  Those two steps combined solved my problem, thank you!!!